# Arch Linux sudo not working in Graphic mode

Tags: arch-linux, sudo

I have a strange problem.

Personal ArchLinux VM `kernel 4.11.2-1-ARCH`, my normal login has sudo access and works fine till last weekend.

Today when I sudo, it gave following error message

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

`su -` not working neither. Yes I know root password as I can login as root from console.

`su -` related logs

```
May 29 15:26:58 Arch unix_chkpwd[882]: check pass; user unknown
May 29 15:26:58 Arch unix_chkpwd[882]: password check failed for user (root)
```

However, if I login via ssh then I can sudo all commands without any problem.
I changed `systemctl` target from `graphical.target` to `multi-user.target` then sudo works again.

My desktop manager is Enlightenment.

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with Enlightenment and the new 4.11.X kernel. See Enlightenment board [here](https://phab.enlightenment.org/T5470).

This has already been [reported](https://phab.enlightenment.org/T5470) on Arch - the interim fix before there's one upstream is to rebuild the kernel with a patch provided there.

While I personally do not use Enlightenment, I run Arch with the LTS kernel because of issues like these. (The current LTS kernel is 4.9.30)

Comment: I updated my ArchLinux today and the problem went away. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. If your password isn't working even though it's correct try executing.

```
faillock --reset
```